# Getting a list of ids based on a certain parent id not having 2 specific rows in the child table

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

That title alone was hard to type out.

I need some help arranging a query. Suppose to following setup:

1 'parent' table
1 'child' table

Here's an example:

```
 id | parent_id | type
---------------------
  1 |         1 | 'BAND'
  2 |         1 | 'AUTHOR'
  3 |         2 | 'BAND'
  4 |         3 | 'BAND'
  5 |         3 | 'AUTHOR'
  6 |         4 | 'BAND'
  7 |         5 | 'BAND'
  8 |         5 | 'AUTHOR'
```

When a 'child' is created, it is supposed to receive 2 rows by default, each identical except for 1 field, the "type" field. Type is a varchar field, containing either 'BAND' or 'AUTHOR'

In the past, there existed only 'BAND'. After doing an update it turned out the script to do so missed a few ids and now there are some children who have both 'BAND' and 'AUTHOR' but some are left stuck on having only 'BAND'

So now I need to find all IDs of the 'child' table for which this combination does not exist.

So in the example, the result should be ids 3 and 6.

I've been wrecking my brain over this, I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent ids readily with conditional aggregation:

```
select parent_id, min(id) as id
from example
group by parent_id
having sum(case when type = 'BAND' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when type = 'AUTHOR' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Or, perhaps the simpler:

```
select parent_id, min(id) as id
from example
group by parent_id
having count(distinct type) = 1;
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks for that. I never reached the point knowing about conditional statements and case statements in SQL queries.